# Linux/Perl Returning list of folders that have not been modified for over x minutes

Tags: linux, perl, sed, find

I have a directory that has multiple folders. I want to get a list of the names of folders that have not been modified in the last `60` minutes.
The folders will have multiple files that will remain old so I can't use `-mmin +60`

I was thinking I could do something with inverse though. Get a list of files that have been modified in `60` minutes `-mmin -60` and then output the inverse of this list.

Not sure to go about doing that or if there is a simpler way to do so?

Eventually I will take these list of folders in a perl script and will add them to a list or something.

This is what I have so far to get the list of folders

```
find /path/to/file -mmin -60 | sed 's/\/path\/to\/file\///' | cut -d "/" -f1 | uniq
```

Above will give me just the names of the folders that have been updated.

Comment: so when you say "folders that have not been modified", you mean "folders that don't contain any files that have been modified"?

Comment: Yes, the folder will only contain files so if any files modified the folder mdtm will also change.

Comment: no, that is not true.  adding, renaming, or deleting files would change the directory's modification time.

Comment: That sed command looks a little odd.  I assume you are trying to do sed 's@/path/to/file/@@' ?

Comment: @ysth Why isn't it true? If a file is changed under a subdirectory of a directory the directories mdtm wouldn't change but if the file is located directly under the folder then the folder mdtm changes I thought.

Comment: because a directory is just like a file; it is "modified" if its contents are changed.  but its files' contents are not its contents.  the list of files is.

Comment: anyway, my point was I wasn't sure from your question which modification time you were actually interested in checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a neat trick to do set operations on text lines like this with sort and uniq. You have already the paths that have been updated. Assume they are in a file called upd. A simple `find -type d` can give you all folders. Lets assume to have them in file all. Then run

```
cat all upd | sort |uniq -c |grep '^1'
```

All paths that appear in both files will have a count of 2 prefixed. All paths only appearing in file all will be prefixed with a 1. The lines prefixed with 1 represent the set difference between all and upd, i.e. the paths that were not touched. (I take it you are able to remove the prefix 1 yourself.)

Surely this can be done with perl or any other scripting language, but this simple sort|uniq is just too nice.-)

Answer (score 1):

The diff command is made for this.

Given two files, "all":

```
# cat all
/dir1/old2
/dir2/old4
/dir2/old5
/dir1/new1
/dir2/old2
/dir2/old3
/dir1/old1
/dir1/old3
/dir1/new4
/dir2/new1
/dir2/old1
/dir1/new2
/dir2/new2
```

and "updated":

```
# cat updated
/dir2/new1
/dir1/new4
/dir2/new2
/dir1/new2
/dir1/new1
```

We can sort the files and run diff.  For this task,I prefer inline sorting:

```
# diff <(sort all) <(sort updated)
4,6d3
< /dir1/old1
< /dir1/old2
< /dir1/old3
9,13d5
< /dir2/old1
< /dir2/old2
< /dir2/old3
< /dir2/old4
< /dir2/old5
```

If there are any files in "updated" that aren't in "all", they'll be prefixed with '>'.